# Uno platform: flyout menu for Android head has excessive gap

Tags: menu, uno-platform, flyout

In the Uno platform, I have a `MenuFlyout` that is `BottomEdgeAlignedRight`. However, on one of my test devices, there's a large gap between the button and the flyout.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Grid ...>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="35" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- tab -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" /> <!-- action button -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  ...

  <Button
    Grid.Column="3"
    Padding="10" >
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icons/more_menu_white.png" />
    <Button.Flyout>
      <MenuFlyout Placement="BottomEdgeAlignedRight">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" Click="OnItem1Clicked" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" Click="OnItem2Clicked" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" Click="OnItem3Clicked" />
      </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
  </Button>
</Grid>
```

Here are some screen shots. As you can see, there's a small gap on UWP and my Android 5 device. But for Android 10, there's a huge gap. I presume the small gaps are by design.

**Windows 10**
[image: Windows 10]

**Android 5**
[image: Android 5]

**Android 10**
[image: Android 10]

Comment: That seems like a bug. Can you report it on the Uno Platform GitHub page please? https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues

Comment: Done: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/5047